# Serialize a jsonArray with two different elements

Tags: java, jackson

I'm consuming an API that gives me an Array containing two different elements.

The response looks like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 99,
      "title": "Title1"
    },
    {
      "id": 100,
      "title": "Title2"
    }
  ],
  {
    "limit": 50,
    "nextOffSet": 50,
    "totalCount": 388
  }
]
```

I can't figure out how to serialize this. Any clue?

Comment: Only thisreponse you got. Or something more on it?

Comment: I think you're going to need to do it (semi) manually, with org.json or the like.

Comment: The list of id's and title's is larger but the structure is that. I need the offset and the total to paginate the list of Id's...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right you want to deserialize json in order to have some java objects to work with in your consumer code.

There are many libraries that can help you to do that. Consider for the example google's GSON lib where you can simply do

```
String jsonString = ... // your json should be here   
List list = new Gson().fromJson(json, List.class);
```

The resulting list will contain contain two elements one will be list for id,title maps, and another will be the map that will contain elements like limit and offset.

For more information on google GSON you can see https://github.com/google/gson

If you want to deserialize json to the object model that consists of simple POJOs you may need to use more specialized libs like Jackson.

Comment: I tried with Jackson but as the two elements are different I was getting a serialize error. I want to avoid to parse the object manually and I like your approach, I will try it, thanks